# Rotating through divs (hide/fade in) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm currently in the process of creating a news carousel. On the left panel i have the three titles of each news item, to the right i have an image associated with that news item, and in the bottom right i have three "navigational blocks" for each item.

In my example, when you click a link on the left, it will display the associated content in the larger right hand panel. This also applies for the navigational blocks in the bottom right. If you click one of those, the associated item will be displayed in the larger panel.

The last thing i need to achieve is an auto rotation of these news items. On load, item one will be displayed with "link 1" highlighted, and "block one" of the navigational blocks highlighted. After say, 10 seconds, "link 2" will become highlighted with the "block 2" highlighted and the associated content in the middle being displayed. So on, so forth.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wDiGy - Here's a code pen version of it so far.

Code highlighted below:

```
<div id="title-container">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="title item" itemID="1">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="title" itemID="2">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="title" itemID="3">Link 3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="image-container">
   <div class="image1 image" itemID="1">1</div>
   <div class="image2 image" itemID="2">2</div>
   <div class="image3 image" itemID="3">3</div>
   <div id="circular-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="circle-title" itemID="1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="circle-title" itemID="2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="circle-title" itemID="3"></a></li>
 </div>
```

jQuery for selecting each item

```
$('.image:first').show();
$('.title, .circle-title').click(function(){
 $('.image').hide();
 var itemID = $(this).attr('itemID');
 $('.image[itemID="' + itemID + '"]').fadeIn('fast');  
});
```

I will be changing the HTML to integrate into the CMS i'm using, but the class names won't be changing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I've managed to get 99% of the way there by fiddling around with it. I now have one hurdle. I'm using .next() to reach each item. If there are three items and it reaches the end, how do you return to the beginning? (PEN Updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution which just involved an if statement to check the length of the item. Once it ended, it was able to loop around correctly.

```
setInterval(function () {
  if ($('.image:visible').next().length === 0) {
    $('.image').hide();
    $('.image:first').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.image:visible').hide().next().fadeIn('fast');
  }
}, 2000); //Milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `setInterval` to trigger the tile change/image change function for every 10 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
    //Code for changing the tile/image
},10000); //Milliseconds
```

You can put your existing function in a variable and use it for click as well as for interval. Also, since you're passing some information with the click, you can store the ids in an array and increment/reset counter after all the images have been cycled through.

Update:

**[Working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/YbeXR/)**

Comment: Hi mate - Thank you very much for your time on this. It looks like it's close as it's "refreshing" the image, but only image one rather than cycling through. Any idea where i would also put the highlights for the title and navigational blocks? Again, really appreciate your time.

Comment: Check the new fiddle... Timer set to 3 seconds.

Comment: It also might be worth pointing out that the itemID's may vary drastically, as the CMS will have filters to display different items. So ultimately you may end up with itemIDs of 45, 92, 12. They will match in the HTML through attributes, it's just the jquery that's tricky for the auto rotate.

Comment: I know, I appreciate that. The reason i've posted on here, is because i'm stuck and seeking (and appreciating) any assistance possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem! Just check the code and I'm sure you should be good to go! Sorry if my comment sounded rude! ;)

Comment: No problem dude! :) Appreciate your time. I've gotten 80% there functionality wise and I've been bashing against ideas for the rotation for awhile now! lol.

Comment: So you're stuck at highlighting the navigation links?

Comment: I'm pretty much there with one minor bug now. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyLus - The only issue remaining is that if i click on any of the navigations (links or blocks) it will refresh that item when it attempts to loop back through again. Other than that, it's all good :)

Comment: Use an `e.preventDefault`.

Comment: I've never heard of that before. Where abouts would that line get situated in my code?

Comment: In your event handler for click. Example:

    $('#somebutton').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hc4py/ (with only links stylized, not bullets)

```
setInterval(function () {
var $cur = $('a.active');
var i = $cur.closest('li').index(); //parent 'li' of first active link

$('.image:visible').hide(); //hide visible image

$cur.removeClass('active');

//if active 'a's parent li is the last one
if ($cur.closest('li').is(':last-child')) { 
    $('.image').eq(0).fadeIn('fast'); //show first image
    $cur.closest('ul').find('li:first-child').find('a.title').addClass('active');
} 


else {
    $('.image').eq(i + 1).fadeIn('fast');//show next image
    $cur.closest('li').next().find('a.title').addClass("active");
}
}, 2000);
```

```
.title.active{color:red;}
```

Comment: Hey RPS - That's got me so close! :) - The only issues I'm facing now is that the click event for clicking on the left links conflicts with the new JS (i'm guessing where it's applying 'active')

Comment: hey. By conflicting u mean, the color of link is not changing to red when you click it? just add the lines `$('a.active').removeClass('active');$(this).addClass('active');` to the click event handler, http://jsfiddle.net/hc4py/1/